# how to split the first, middle and last names, and print it as last name, first initial middle initial c++

Tags: c++

I have to intput first, middle and last name of a person and the output should be last name,
first initial and middle initial if the name has one, but I am having problems trying to take
out the middle initial and when I don put a middle name the code prints last name, first initial
and last initial any solutions?

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
    
       /* Type your code here. */
       string firstName, middleName, lastName, fullName;
       
       getline(cin, fullName);
       
       char firstSpace = fullName.find_first_of(' ');
       char secondSpace = fullName.find_last_of(' ');
       firstName = fullName.substr(0, firstSpace);
       middleName = fullName.substr(fullName.find(' ') + 1 , fullName.find (' ') );
    
       if (secondSpace < 0) {
         lastName = fullName.substr(firstSpace);
         cout << lastName + ", " + firstName.substr(0,1)+ "." << endl;
         
       }
       else{
         lastName = fullName.substr(secondSpace + 1);
         cout << lastName + ", " + firstName.substr(0,1) + "." + middleName.substr(0,1) + "." << endl;
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What's the format of your input line when middle name is present and when is not present?

Comment: This seems overly complicated.  Why not put `fullName` into a `std::istringstream` and read strings out until input fails?  Then you'll know how many names there are and take appropriate action.  Or use a `std::regex` to match the different supported name styles and even extract the middle initial automagically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `firstSpace == secondSpace` for the `if` statment.

`str.find_fisrt_of` and `str.find_last_of` returns the index of them. So if there is only 1 space in between, it will return true and enter that logic. For the same reason, `firstSpace` and `secondSpace` should probably be declared `int` instead of `char`.

Also you are getting your middle name wrong. `str.substr` takes in two numbers, the first one is the starting index of it, and the second one is the length of it. So instead, you should be doing

```
middleName = fullName.substr(firstSpace + 1 , secondSpace - firstSpace - 1);
```

Also you could get the first letter of the string by using `str.front()`, so you are not creating a new string.

Rather than using `+` to connect different strings, you should use `<<`. Using `+`, you are actually adding all of them in to a temporary string object. Using `<<`, you are just pushing them into output.

And the majority of your `if` `else` will be the same, instead you could have this part written outside of it:

```
lastName = fullName.substr(secondSpace + 1);
cout << lastName << ", " << firstName.front() << ".";
```

Then:

```
if(firstSpace == secondSpace)
    cout << middleName.front() << ".";
cout << endl;
```

Also, people will mention [why `using namespace std` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

So my final code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    
int main() {
    
  std::string firstName, middleName, lastName, fullName;
  std::getline(std::cin, fullName);
       
  int firstSpace = fullName.find_first_of(' ');
  int secondSpace = fullName.find_last_of(' ');

  firstName = fullName.substr(0, firstSpace);
  middleName = fullName.substr(firstSpace + 1 , secondSpace - firstSpace - 1);
  lastName = fullName.substr(secondSpace + 1);

  std::cout << lastName << ", " << firstName.front() << ".";
  if(firstSpace != secondSpace)
  {
    std::cout << middleName.front() << "."; 
  } 
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```